# Why selected index fires only once the Index of the ListItem is changed?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

Consider a `asp:dropdownlist` which fires `SelectedIndexChangedEvent` based on `listitem index`.....

But why the event doesn't fire for the same `listitem index` when selected again....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it didn't **change**.

You can solve this by resetting the value after each change.

Comment: How should one do that @SLaks