# C# combobox selected index changed fires old value in another combobox

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I have found the closest reference of my problem on these links:

> [ComboBox has its old value after Clear()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306719/combobox-has-its-old-value-after-clear)
>   [Why selected index fires only once the Index of the ListItem is changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406681/why-selected-index-fires-only-once-the-index-of-the-listitem-is-changed)

I have 4 comboboxes: `cmbcountry`, `cmbstate`, `cmbdistrict` and `cmbcity`. `cmbcountry` populates on load event by `GetCountry()` method. `cmbstate` populates by `GetState(countryid)` method, which takes `cmbcountry`'s selectedvalue as argument and returns a list of relevant states and so on for `cmbdistrict` and `cmbcity`...

Problem is on selecting different item in `cmbState`, `cmbDistrct` is not populating with the proper items.

.E.g. states :"madhya pradesh", "Utter pradesh" , "Rajsthan"
For "Rajsthan", cmbdistrict is populating with relavent value, but for "Utter pradesh", cmbdistrict still has old value.

Here is the relevant code:

```
private void TestForm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmbCountry.ItemSource = Lookups.Lookup.GetCountries();
}

private void cmbCountry_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmbState.Text = "";
    cmbState.Clear();
    cmbState.SelectedIndex = -1;
    cmbState.SelectedItem = null;
    //cmbState.Items.Clear();
    int countryId = Convert.ToInt32(cmbCountry.SelectedValue);
    cmbState.ItemSource = Lookups.Lookup.GetStates(countryId);
}

private void cmbState_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmbDistrict.Text = "";
    cmbDistrict.Clear();
    cmbDistrict.SelectedIndex = -1;
    cmbDistrict.SelectedItem = null;
    //cmbDistrict.Items.Clear();            
    int stateId = Convert.ToInt32(cmbState.SelectedValue);
    cmbDistrict.ItemSource = Lookups.Lookup.GetDistricts(stateId);
}

private void cmbDistrict_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmbCity.Text = "";
    cmbCity.Clear(); 
    cmbCity.SelectedIndex = -1;
    cmbCity.SelectedItem = null;
    //cmbCity.Items.Clear();
    int DistrictId = Convert.ToInt32(cmbDistrict.SelectedValue);
    cmbCity.ItemSource = Lookups.Lookup.GetCities(DistrictId);
}

private void cmbBank_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int bankId = Convert.ToInt32(cmbBank.SelectedValue);
    cmbControlBranch.ItemSource = Lookups.Lookup.GetBranches(bankId);
}
```

I have all above methods to clear previous data in comboboxes ...and items.clear() is giving an error if i am using it.

Please tell me if there is any other relevant reference which I am missing .

Comment: What is the error that you get from "items.clear()"

Comment: Are you sure "Lookups.Lookup.GetDistricts(stateId);" is returning the list that you want? Can you post that code?

Comment: When I put try to access combobox.SelectedValue it gives me a null value, maybe try combobox.SelectedIndex?

Comment: Combobox does NOT have a Clear() method.  Do you mean Items.Clear()?  What version of .NET?   This is Forms or WPF?